# Get id of field input in sonata using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony-sonata

I use symfony and sonataAdminBundle, in my ProductAdmin Class I have a form with many input type : And i like to get the Id of one of this input called 'prixAchat' : with inspect element I see that sonata generate an auto prefix value before the id like this : **s5988300197635_prixAchat** so

So I tried to use this code :

```
prixAchat = document.getElementById('form [id$="_prixAchat"]').value
```

But always the result is null

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to get input? I think the code should be `prixAchat = $('input [id$="_prixAchat"]').val()`

Answer (score 0):

prixAchat = document.getElementById('_prixAchat').id

use id instead of value at the end

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:51

Comment: So the problem is that your selector is invalid. You need to pass actual id into document.getElementById. Do you know anything unique about your element?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but `document.getElementById` looks like not suitable in your case. Try this:

```
prixAchat = $('form [id$="_prixAchat"]').val()
```

Comment: Empty string :(

Comment: may be your input is empty. what output will you have in this case: console.log ( $('form [id$="_prixAchat"]') )

Comment: it render all the input of _prixAchat ,

Comment: the value does not null :(

Comment: ok, what do you have in this case console.log ( $('form [id$="_prixAchat"]').val() )

Comment: I have : undefined

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
prixAchat = $("#{{ form.vars.id }}_prixAchat").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id with **{{ admin.uniqid  }}**

Here is an example:

```
var prixAchatId= $("#{{ admin.uniqid  }}_prixAchat")
```

so the {{ admin.uniqid  }} gives you that s5988300197635